# clocking on spartan6 FPGAs

Tags: fpga, spartan

[Spartan 6 clocking resources](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug382.pdf). The link here refers to the clocking resources of spartan-6 FPGA.  I am using the DCM-CLKGEN primitive described in the link, to generate a divide-by-8 clock based on an input clock. It works fine as long as the input clock is stable.

But now i sweep the input clock at every 90 us by +/-5%. I see that although the DCM does not lose lock, it takes very long (15 to 20 us) to change the output freq after changing the input frequency. This is for me undesirable. Any suggestions?

This question was posted [on the Xilinx forum](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Spartan-Family-FPGAs/changing-input-frequency-of-dcm-clkgen/td-p/558422) and the suggestion was to reset the DCM everytime it loses lock. But the problem is that the DCM is not losing lock.

Comment: try using one of the PLL primitives.

Comment: PLL is better then DCM for varying frequency input?

Comment: This question refers to the analog parts of an FPGA and should IMHO be posted on EE-stackoverflow.
It is also a cross-post from the [Xilinx Forum](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Spartan-Family-FPGAs/changing-input-frequency-of-dcm-clkgen/td-p/558422) and it would be polite of you to at least (a) be clear about that and (b) repeat the relevant inputs you got there already here! Also a linkt to the specs/datasheet of the specific FPGA and its DCM would be helpful.

Comment: @mbschenkel i have taken your suggestions and edited the post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into Xilinx and don't know much of its internal structure. However, if you need just to divide input clock by 8, you can make it on logic (some simple counter) and then inject output of final flipflop into clock network of your Spartan chip.

From the general point of view, PLL also can fail in tracking heavily or abruptly varying input clock.

Comment: how can i use counter logic to generate a faster clock? also, how can I handle varying input with counters?

Comment: You have just said "to generate a divide-by-8 clock", so you can easily divide clocks (make clock's period greater) in logic. Of course it is near to impossible to multiply clocks (make period shorter) in logic. The counter will just increment on every positive (or negative) edge of clock, it won't care of a clock frequency, until it is fast enough at all to handle some faster clock.

Comment: @lvd...yea this is the problem. My input clock frequency is 13.56 Mhz and i expect an output of 13.56x8=108.48Mhz.                                        In general lets say Fin is the input freq, Fout is the output freq- Then       Fout = 8xFin and Fin varies at Fin+/-5%. Thats the reason I use DCM. The problem is that the DCM is taking too long to change Fout when Fin changes.

Comment: @SaiGautam: Have you evaluated to use dedicated PLL / VCO ICs instead? A part that is made for this purpose will be more likely to provide the dynamic response you need than an FPGA which is made for constant frequency inputs and mostly synchronous digital logic.

Comment: @mbschenkel I tried to use PLL but unfortunately the Fmin for the PLL is 19Mhz whereas I am operating at 13.56Mhz +/- 5%

Comment: @SaiGautam: I was not talking about the *internal* PLL of the FPGA, but rather an *external* component (e.g. something in the spirit of a [CD54HCT4046A](http://www.ti.com/product/cd54hct4046a)) to either solve your problem entirely outside the FPGA or to generate an N-times higher frequency. In any case it is rather unconventional to run an FPGA at variable clock frequency, so it might also help to explain us *why* you are trying to do that in the first place - maybe there are alternative solutions (e.g. oversampling)?

Comment: @mbschenkel thats a very good question. Until 2 months ago everything was working fine because the input clock was fixed. But now as a new requirement  the input clock is sweeping and so synchronization inside FPGA is causing headaches. The problem is that this calls for complete redesign of architecture but due to costs we are trying to preserve the design and imeplement hacks. Do you know if its possible to imeplement DDS logic in an FPGA without LOGICore IPs?